# Elementor not loading Panels to Edit

Tags: javascript, elementor

Not sure whats happening here.
I have got the same site on the same host, 2 different installs.. one works perfect..
and the other, everytime I go to add new page, I'm getting these errors.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'autop')
at ([siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=639e14271099dc3d85bf:10:34344
at Kn ([siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=639e14271099dc3d85bf:10:34415)
at [siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=639e14271099dc3d85bf:10:36294
at Array.reduce ()
at Wn ([siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=639e14271099dc3d85bf:10:36270)
at [siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.min.js?ver=43e40e04f77d598ede94:26:69119
at i ([siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.min.js?ver=43e40e04f77d598ede94:26:53083)
at [siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.min.js?ver=43e40e04f77d598ede94:26:69384
at Array.map ()
at [siteurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.min.js?ver=43e40e04f77d598ede94:26:69354

Tried reverting Elementor back a couple of versions no luck, turned off all plugins and just left elementor and elementor pro on, still no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.